# Doctrine 2 Close Connection

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine 2 PDO with mysql.

When stress testing the server, mysql reports a lot of aborted connections (up-to 20%).

I am trying to locate the issue.

Mysql manual suggests to ensure that connections to the database are closed properly.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/communication-errors.html

I can't find any information if doctrine actually closes connections or not, or uses persistent connections.

Also, is there anything else that can account for aborted connections? I am at loss here.

PS. Server is ubuntu 10.04, nginx 1.x, php 5.3.5 (fpm) and mysql 5.1.41

Comment: Doctrine2 manual recommends using APC or some other caching mechanism. Failing to provide one might result in lots of connections. Do you have any?

Comment: I have APC cache for metadata and queries. Do you have a link to the manual where they describe how to cache connections?

Comment: No, but if cache is disabled, Doctrine will have to flush changes morefrequently, openening more connections to the DB.

Comment: Doctrine doesn't flush anything. The developer does. The question was about how to close connections in doctrine. And you obviously don't know the answer.

Comment: I _know_ how to close connections, but I _doubt_ that it will help. [Here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal/2.0/api) is the API reference, use it like `$em->getConnection()->close()`. But Doctrine has close connections automatically, so you shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From what I've observed, Doctrine uses persistent connections.

We've stumbled upon a problem, launching unit tests in symfony2, where the database was spammed with connections in "Sleep" status. The solution that worked for us:

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->close();
```

Comment: Can you tell me when you call close? We try to execute this in kernel.terminate or kernel.response events but the connections are still hanging in mysql.

Comment: I was using it in unit tests so it was in the tearDown method. Sorry I can't help you much.

Comment: I still see the list of open connections grow. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->close();
```

seems to work, but works 'better' in some php versions if you add

```
 gc_collect_cycles()
```

after closing connections. 
I'm still having that kind of issues in older php version, may be something related with the garbage collector I guess.
Will keep you updated if I find a final solution for all php versions

Comment: In my case gc_collect_cycles() solved my 'too many connections' error during executing PHPUnit tests

Answer (score 0):

I have found this tweak:

https://sroze.io/phpunit-mysql-too-many-connections-error-ab52cd5798c5

Setting `processIsolation="true"` option in PhpUnit XML options file seems to do the trick.