# Unit testing: "Too many open files" and "Too many connections" errors after upgrade to symfony 2.5

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

It looks like some system resources are holding in Symfony 2.5 while tests are running.

I have a Symfony2 project with more than 200 functional tests. 
With Symfony 2.3 and 2.4 everything worked, but after upgrade to 2.5 I began receiving an error (I use Mac OS X):

```
failed to open stream: Too many open files
```

I googled a little and changed max_files parameter in system config.

After that I began receiving another error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections'
```

OK, I changed the max-connections parameter in MySQL, but it looks like something is wrong after upgrade. Like some system resources are holding.

After downgrade back to 2.4 everything becomes OK again.

Maybe now I have to close some resources or connections manually somewhere? Or the problem is somewhere else?

UPD: I have found one more question with same problem: [Too many connection during unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182087/too-many-connection-during-unit-testing)

Comment: So you managed to resolve both issues - `Too many open files` by increasing `max_files` in **php.ini** ... and `Too many connections` by increasing `max_connections` in **my.cnf** ... Now what's your question exactly? Please clarify.

Comment: Nifr, I edited my question. Anyway, I think it is abnormal. I want to understand the reasons. Tests began using more resources or connections? But why? Or some resources that have to be closed remains opened? But why? Do I have to close them manually somewhere in the code? What changed?

Comment: sounds like your phpunit tests dont close the connections cleanly..
do you have an `$this->em->close();` in your tearDown? and between 2.4 and 2.5 its adviced to use the KernelTestCase instead of the WebTestCase, dont know if its makes a diffrence. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html

Comment: Rufinus, I tried to close the connection in tearDown, but had no effect. I log all my queries while developing and after tests ends there were a lot of "Quit" entries. As I understand, it means that there are a lot of opened connections and all of them are closing only after all tests are finished. Before 2.5 it was not so.
About KernelTestCase - I am also not sure. WebTestCase just extends KernelTestCase. And the only own function it has is createClient().

Answer (score 0):

Just execute "ulimit -n 10000" before running unit tests.
Another solution (I think the best solution) is to use "in memory" database. Your tests will run faster.

Comment: I have the same errors with an in-memory sqlite DB.